# Awk column value in file 1 is in the range of two columns in file 2

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I modified the question based on the comments.

I would like to match two files: if $4 in file 1 is in the range of $3 and $4 in file 2, I would like to print file 1 with $6 in file 2. If there is no match, I would like to print NA in the output. If there are overlapping ranges, I would like to print the first match (sorting based on $4 of file 1).

File 1:

```
1   rs537182016 0   8674590 A   C
1   rs575272151 0   69244805    G   C
1   rs544419019 0   69244469    G   C
1   rs354682    0   1268900 G   C
```

File 2:

```
18  16  8674587 8784575 +   ABAT
10349   17  69148007    69244815    -   ABCA10
23461   17  69244435    69327182    -   ABCA5
```

Output:

```
1   rs537182016 0   8674590 A   C ABAT
1   rs575272151 0   69244805    G   C ABCA10
1   rs544419019 0   69244469    G   C ABCA10
1   rs354682    0   1268900 G   C NA
```

I tried the following based on previous answers, but it did not work. The output is an empty file.

```
awk 'FNR == NR { val[$1] = $4 }
     FNR != NR { if ($1 in val && val[$1] >= $3 && val[$1] <= $4)
                     print $1, val[$1], $6
               }' file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: is each value in the 2nd column (`$2`) unique within `file1`? if not, what set of columns is unique in `file1`? please also update the question to provide details on what you mean by `did not work` ... syntax error (and if so please add complete error to question)? no output? wrong output (and if so, please add the wrong output to the question)?

Comment: are you looking for inclusive ranges (eg, `a <= b <=c`) or exclusive ranges (eg, `a < b < c`)? how do we determine which match to make (and display) when an entry from `file1` matches multilpe lines in `file2`, eg, both `rs575272151/69244805` and `rs544419019/69244469` match 2 different (overlapping) ranges from `file2` ... but your expected output only shows a single match so how do we determine which match to display?

Comment: `$1` in file 1 is always `1`, so you're overwriting the same `val[$]` each time. And none of the `$1` in file 2 match `$1` in file 1, so `$1 in val` will never be true.

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes, each value in $2 of file 1 is unique. I am looking for inclusive ranges. For example, 8674587 8784575 is the range in file 2 (columns $3 and $4), and $4 of file 1 lies in this range.

Comment: The code never uses `$2` in file 1. Should `val[$1]` be `val[$2]`?

Comment: The second and third lines in `file1` have `$4` that falls in the range `$3 .. $4` of lines of the second and third lines in `file2`.  What are the criteria for deciding which entry from `file1` should be printed?  A simple rule makes it 'print 5 lines in total'.  A less simple rule does something like "after an entry from `file1` is used once, it should not be used again", which can be achieved by deleting the saved value or by changing the saved value to `0`.

Comment: I edited the question based on the comments for a more logical output.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm still confused.  You reordered the columns in the desired output which makes it harder to generate the output (but far from impossible).  More significantly, it is not clear what you mean by "first match" given that you expect `rs575272151` and `rs544419019` to appear, but by many reasonable interpretations of "first match" the same value should appear twice.  You've also added a line to the output that corresponds to a line from `file1` that has no match in `file2` — that's devious and needs explaining too. Sadly, programming is unforgiving about such details.

Comment: while the additional details is helpful ... you've flipped the output so that we're now showing all of `file1` plus a lookup value from `file2` ... you still haven't defined what you mean by ***first*** match (ie, are you sorting `file2` by 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 6th column to determine `'first'`? is `'first'` determine by physical position in `file2`?); with the new, completely different output your code is now even more nonsensical (do you have any newer code that attempts to generate the new set of outputs?)

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes, sorting based on $4 of file 1. If it was already matched to the range, move onto the next line.

Comment: sorting by `$4` in `file1` doesn't make sense; what we need is the sorting method for the contents in `file2`; case in point ... in the expected output ... why does the 3rd line end with `ABCA5` and not `ABCA10` since `ABCA10` represents the `'first'` match in `file2`?  (assuming order is based on position, aka row number, in `file2`)

Comment: I modified the output including ABCA10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- in the case of multiple matches OP has stated we only use the `'first'` match; OP hasn't (yet) defined `'first'` so I'm going to assume it means the  order in which lines appear in `file2` (aka the line number)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { min[++n]=$3                                # save 1st file values in arrays; use line number as index
          max[n]=$4
          col6[n]=$6
          next
        }
        { for (i=1;i<=n;i++)                         # loop through 1st file entries
              if (min[i] <= $4 && $4 <= max[i]) {    # if we find a range match then ...
                 print $0, col6[i]                   # print current line plus column #6 from 1st file and then ...
                 next                                # skip to next line of input; this keeps us from matching on additional entries from 1st file
              }
          print $0, "NA"                             # if we got here there was no match so print current line plus "NA"
        }
' file2 file1
```

**NOTE:** make note of the order of the input files; the first answer (below) was based on an input of `file1 file2`; this answer requires the order of the input files to be flipped, ie, `file2 file1`

This generates:

```
1   rs537182016 0   8674590 A   C ABAT
1   rs575272151 0   69244805    G   C ABCA10
1   rs544419019 0   69244469    G   C ABCA10
1   rs354682    0   1268900 G   C NA
```

---

---

---

**NOTE:** following is based on OP's original question and expected output (revision #2); OP has since modified the expected output to such an extent that the following answer is no longer valid ...

Assumptions:

- in `file1` both `rs575272151 / 69244805` and `rs544419019 / 69244469` match 2 different (overlapping) ranges from `file2` but OP has only showed one set of matches in the expected output; from this I'm going to assume ...
- once a match is found for an entry from `file1`, remove said entry from any additional matching; this will eliminate multiple matches for `file1` entries
- once a match is found for a line from `file2` then stop looking for matches for that line (ie, go to the next intput line from `file2`); this will eliminate multiple-matches for `file2`
- OP has not provided any details on how to determine which mulit-match to keep so we'll use the first match we find

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { val[$2]=$4; next }
        { for (i in val)                            # loop through list of entries from 1st file ...
              if ($3 <= val[i] && val[i] <= $4) {   # looking for a range match and if found ... 
                 print $0,i                         # print current line plus 2nd field from 1st file and then ...
                 delete val[i]                      # remove 1st file entry from further matches and ... 
                 next                               # skip to next line of input from 2nd file, ie, stop looking for additional matches for the current line
              }
        }
' file1 file2
```

This generates:

```
18  16  8674587 8784575 +   ABAT rs537182016
10349   17  69148007    69244815    -   ABCA10 rs575272151
23461   17  69244435    69327182    -   ABCA5 rs544419019
```

**NOTES:**

- the `for (i in val)` construct is not guaranteed to process the array entries in a consistent manner; net result is that in the instance where there are multiple matches we simply match on the 'first' array entry provided by `awk`; if this 'random' nature of the `for (i in val)` is not acceptable then OP will need to update the question with additional details on how to handle multiple matches
- for this particular case we actually generate the same output as expected by OP, but the assignments of `rs575272151` and `rs544419019` could just as easily be reversed (due to the nature of the `for (i in val)` construct)

Comment: That's pretty much the answer I came up with — with the questions that I asked in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73126401/awk-column-value-in-file-1-is-in-the-range-of-two-columns-in-file-2#comment129153355_73126401).  My first pass didn't have the `delete` statement, so I got 5 lines of output, which isn't what the OP said they wanted, but then they didn't explain how to get the result they seem to want.

Comment: FWIW: the Awk on macOS Big Sur gave me the opposite associations, so `rs544419019` was printed with `10349` and `rs575272151` was printed with `23461`.  This confirms your point about the instability of the ordering.

Comment: This script uses the lines from `file1` in the sequence they appear: `FNR == NR { seq[++n] = $2; val[$2] = $4 } FNR != NR { for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) { i = seq[j]; if (i in val && val[i] >= $3 && val[i] <= $4) { print $0, i; delete val[i]; next } } } `.  It could probably do `delete seq[j];` too, but it isn't necessary.